# use *ngIf in nb-menu items

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap, nebular

How Can I use `*ngIf` in `<nb-menu [items]="items">` menu?
I got something like this

```
<nb-menu [items]="items"> </nb-menu>
```

and in my .ts

```
items: NbMenuItem[] = [
    {
      title: 'Aliases',
      icon: 'list-outline',
      link: 'aliases'
    },
    {
      title: 'Aliases to accept',
      icon: 'checkmark-outline',
      link: 'toAccept'
    },
```

i want to grant access for "toAccept" only for admin

Before I did something like this:

```
  <li *ngIf="showForAdmin">
        <a href="/toAccept" class="nav-link" routerLink="toAccept">
          <nb-icon icon="checkmark-outline"></nb-icon>Aliases to accept
        </a>
      </li>
```

and it works fine

How Can I do something similarin nebular?

Comment: do you want to show/hide nb-menu component?

Comment: Yes but depending on the user's role ( I got service for this and own backend )

Comment: <nb-menu *ngIf="showForAdmin" [items]="items"> </nb-menu> is it possible?

Comment: @varundhariyal no it doesn't work. I tried like this.

Comment: What was the error?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the menu items you need depending on variables in your .ts file

```
import { USER_MENU_ITEMS } from './pages-menu';
import { NbMenuService, NbMenuItem } from '@nebular/theme';

export class PagesComponent {

  menu = USER_MENU_ITEMS;
  showForAdmin = true;

adminMenuItem: NbMenuItem[] = [
    {
      title: 'Admin',
      group: true,
    },
    {
      title: 'Management',
      icon: 'browser-outline',
      children: [
    {
      title: 'User Details',
      link: '/path/users',
    },
    ],
   },
  ]


constructor( private nbMenuService: NbMenuService ) {
    this.addAdminMenu(this.showForAdmin);
  }

  addAdminMenu(showForAdmin){
    if (showForAdmin === true)
    {
      this.nbMenuService.addItems(this.adminMenuItem);
    }
  }
```

}

Comment: Hello @JayDee can you please share in brief i need to role base security.